# SSIS foreach loop takes wrong file

Tags: foreach, ssis

I'm developing a SSIS Package that copies contents of specific files to a database. In this package I mak heavy use of the foreach container. Today I came across a strange behavior and have no clue whats wrong. In one of the containers I filter for "VBFA*.txt". But for some reason the container also gets triggered for a file called "VBAP.D2014211.T204008397.R000564.txt". When I change any part of that filename it doesn't trigger the container anymore. Additionally there are plenty of other files that start with "VBAP" and don't trigger the container. What could be the reason for this behavior?

Here is the enumerators implementation:

```
<DTS:ForEachEnumerator>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">{6E07E755-700D-4D7D-9550-E08DA5B81264}
</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="DTSID">
{f0ceed84-f95c-404c-8794-2eec0155d1a6}</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="Description"></DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="CreationName">DTS.ForEachFileEnumerator.2</DTS:Property>
<DTS:ObjectData>
  <ForEachFileEnumeratorProperties>
    <FEFEProperty Folder="\\desoswi0204vs\etldata\transfers\out\DP"/>
    <FEFEProperty FileSpec="VBFA*.txt"/>
    <FEFEProperty FileNameRetrievalType="0"/>
    <FEFEProperty Recurse="0"/>
  </ForEachFileEnumeratorProperties>
</DTS:ObjectData>
</DTS:ForEachEnumerator>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what your For Each Loop container's Enumeration Configuration is like? That could hold some clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked the paths contents with dir /x and  the short name of my file is wrong. For the file "VBAP.D2014211.T204008397.R000564.txt" the shortname is "VBFA08~1.TXT". The full result is:

01.08.2014  11:02         1.067.169 VBFA08~1.TXT VBAP.D2014211.T204008397.R000564.txt

I have absolutely no clue, what is happening here and how to stop it. This violates every rule I've found regarding the short filename creation. I leave this as the answer for everybody else who is comming accross this beahvior, which is also the case for c# Directory.GetFiles

Comment: Good on you for posting your findings. This intrigues me and I found this bug report saying it is by design (!)  https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/321020/for-each-file-enumerator-matches-incorrect-files. But it also says the short name generated _depends on the other files in the folder_. This might be why the short name is unexpected (contains an F). If this is the only file in the folder does it generate the same short name?

Comment: I also found the reason why it is named that way. There is a huge count of files starting with VBAP. When the shortnames are generated it seems to run out of numbers for naming it and thus genrates them with hex numbers. This leeds at some point to a "number" starting with "FA" and the only part of the original filename that is used is the leading "VB". The used numbers get so long, that only two letters of the original filename are maintained.

Comment: Certainly makes sense. If you're looking for a practical solution, there might be other ways to do what you're doing.

Comment: In my case I could just adjust my pattern to "VBFA.*.txt" since the short names don't support multiple periods and the naming scheme for the dataexports puts a period after the tables name.

Comment: Can you try it, test it, and if it works post it back as an answer and make the internet a smarter place :)

Comment: Works in this case :)